# Moving updated version of WordPress site into live site from QA Server to Live Server

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a live WordPress website which is based on WooCommerce, now I have another website (uploaded on QA Server) which is updated version of live site, Some extra plugins also installed in it.

Now I have to replace live site with Updated version of it which is uploaded on QA Server, plus I have to save all transactions of live site (so replacing database is not a good option).

What to do?

Comment: Thank you so much for help, I've done it before but it doesn't solved my problem :) I've done UI changes again on LIVE Site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite tool for migrating WP databases is: [WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/)

But the answer largely depends on what you've updated on the testing site. Using the above plugin you could pull all the database tables *except* `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` and that should get you any new options you've configured with your new plugins without overwriting your Orders.

Granted this means you would you not automatically pull in any new pages/posts/products, etc either. But for that could use the Import method described in sanki's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I haven't tried this tool before, I'll definitely try it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your QA server's wp-admin.
2. Then hover over => "Tools"
3. Click on export and then select "orders".
4. Then hit "Download Export File" button. You'll get an xml file as download.
5. Now move on to the LIVE site,login to admin panel.
6. Again hover over => "Tools"
7. Click on Import and then "Wordpress"
8. Then on file window select the exported xml file and you are done.

Transactions will be imported on the live site.